# Sum value with date condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have following value in my table:

```
daytime  |user|value
22Apr2018|A   |1000
04May2018|A   |100
05May2018|A   |200
05May2018|B   |700
09May2018|C   |1000
10May2018|C   |800
15May2018|A   |1000
16May2018|A   |250
17May2018|A   |250
```

How can i sum the value by user and date if there are only one day gap in between?

The expected result will be:

```
daytime  |user|value
22Apr2018|A   |1000
04May2018|A   |300
05May2018|B   |700
09May2018|C   |1800
15May2018|A   |1500
```

Comment: Thanks @utsav, didnt know it shown up horribly, was wanted to edit it, you are way faster :p

Comment: @RyanWilson The OP asked to sum "if there are only one day gap in between" - truncating to start of the month will not solve this problem.

Comment: @Utsav I need to group the value to the first date if there are continuous value , eg. for 04May2018|A   |100 and 05May2018|A   |200, i need to group it under 04May2018, with value 300

Comment: Search for `gaps and islands` implementation in Oracle.

Comment: Are you doing the GROUP BY daytime?

Comment: @WiLLyxVKei, group by Daytime (first date if following days have value as well) and user

Comment: what happens if there are more than 2 values with a difference of one day?
Let's say I add this value to your table : 
`06May2018 | A   |200`

Comment: @Sirmyself, on one day, one user will not have more than one value, it is possible in one day, two user with two different value.

Comment: @akira Are you saying that it is impossible for a user to have more than two consecutive days with a value in your table?

Comment: @Sirmyself, yes, i have edit the question make it more clearer, see the record from 15May until 17May, belong to user A, but the expected result should only see the first date 15May with the sum of 15May until 17May

Comment: Why do you want the first row in your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY daytime) - 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY daytime) grp
  FROM tab t
)
SELECT MIN(daytime) AS daytime, "user", SUM(value) AS value
FROM cte
GROUP BY "user", grp
ORDER BY daytime;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8cc204df86ff0b91a4d436460a13da82)**

**EDIT:**

> *the solution seem doesn't work if there are different date gap with same user*

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY daytime) 
   - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY daytime) grp
  FROM tab t
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT c.*, 
    CASE WHEN daytime - 1 = 
     COALESCE(LAG(daytime) OVER(PARTITION BY "user", grp ORDER BY daytime),
     daytime-1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS grp2
  FROM cte c
), cte3 AS (
  SELECT c2.*, SUM(grp2) OVER(PARTITION BY "user", grp ORDER BY daytime) AS s
  FROM cte2 c2
)
SELECT MIN(daytime) AS daytime, "user", SUM(value) AS value
FROM cte3
GROUP BY "user", grp, s
ORDER BY "user", grp, daytime;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2310cfc63cc58a3d07410f348753f6cf)**

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 ! If i wanted to make it even simpler, with only one user, how should it be?

Comment: hi @lad2025, the solution seem doesn't work if there are different date gap with same user, for example: 04May2018|A   |100
05May2018|A   |200, 08May2018|A   |200
09May2018|A   |300, 10May2018|A   |100
11May2018|A   |700.. the query will give one row of result which sum all date, instead of 3 rows of result with 04May2018 = 300, 08May2018 = 500 and 10May2018 = 800

Comment: @akira Ok, fixed.